# Rails: How to render different versions of a "show" view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a model "User". I defined it in my routes.rb with `resources :users`. I want to be able to render different versions of the same user. To see if it would work, here's what I tried in my routes.rb:

```
get "users/:id_alt", :to => "users#alt", :as => :user
```

and in my controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def alt
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

But when I navigated to `users/1`, I got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#alt
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

and the error pointed to this line under `def alt`:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Anyone know how to remedy this error or accomplish this another way?

Comment: What do you mean by "different versions"? How would expect Rails to know that the `1` in `/users/1` is supposed to be `:id_alt` rather than `:id`? Why are you looking for `params[:id]` in a controller whose route talks about `:id_alt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have set your route to use `:id_alt`

```
get "users/:id_alt", :to => "users#alt", :as => :user
```

So the controller is assuming the value in that location should have the name :id_alt not :id. You are not going to be able to have both routes set up this way, but you could do this:

```
get "users/alt/:id_alt", :to => "users#alt", :as => :alt_user
get "users/:id", :to => "users#show", :as => :user
```

You will be able to use these path methods: `alt_user_path` and `user_path`

And your controller should look like this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def alt
  @user = User.find(params[:id_alt])
  render :show
end
```

Running `rake routes` will result in this:

```
alt_user GET  /users/alt/:id_alt(.:format) users#alt
user GET  /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
```

Comment: I followed your code exactly, but now going to users/1 returns a "Template is missing" error, any idea why?

Comment: You will also need a view file called `alt.html.erb` in `app/views/users/` folder. Or you can put `render :show` at the end of the alt method in your controller. See my edit.

Comment: Hm, I just noticed that "alt_user_path(@user) just directs to user_path(@user). Should I be using a different path syntax?